# Body height shorter than container

Tags: html, css, document-body

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I'm starting to have my first dilemmas.
I'm in the middle of creating a fake CV page but have a problem: basically I don't understand why my body and html and container are shorter than my content. I would like them to arrive at the bottom of the document but I don't manage to. I've tried everything but I guess it's plenty of errors on few divs.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#mail {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 100px;
  right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
}
#phone {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 20px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 50%;
}
#name {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}
#surname {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 20px;
}
hr {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
#block-job {
  position: relative;
  top: 350px;
  width: 30%;
  left: 380px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.single-block {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.link {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.description {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
#name:hover,
#mail:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.year {
  position: relative;
  right: 80px;
  top: 25px;
}
#block-bio {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  top: 385px;
  right: 320px;
}
#about {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
img {
  width: 555px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="left">
    <div id="contact">
      <p id="mail">steven@steven.com</p>
      <p id="phone">(44)512345678</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id="logo">
      <p id="name">STEVEN</p>
      <p id="surname">STEVENSON</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
  <hr>
  <div id="block-job">
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2016</span>
      <div class="title">Artnet, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artnet.com</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artnet.com is an art market website. It is operated by Artnet Worldwide Corporation, which has headquarters in New York, in the United States</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2016</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2014</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2010</span>
      <div class="title">Artnet, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artnet.com is an art market website. It is operated by Artnet Worldwide Corporation, which has headquarters in New York, in the United States</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2008</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2006</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2006</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-block">
      <span class="year">2006</span>
      <div class="title">Artsy, New York</div>
      <span class="link">artsy.net</span>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Artsy is the online resource for art collecting and education. Discover, learn about, and buy art you'll love, featuring fine art, design, and photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-bio">
    <div id="photo">
      <img src="http://www.davidejackson.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gary_clark_jr_summerfest_2014_milwaukee_album_packaging_music_photography_live_show_warner_brothers_records_23.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="inner-bio">
      <div id="about">About Me</div>
      <div id="bio">
        <p>James Newell Osterberg, Jr., better known by the stage name Iggy Pop (/ˈɪɡi pɒp/ born April 21, 1947), is an American singer-songwriter, musician and actor. He is the vocalist of influential proto-punk band The Stooges, who reunited in 2003, and
          has been known for his outrageous and unpredictable stage antics. Pop's music has encompassed a number of styles over the course of his career, including garage rock, hard rock, new wave, jazz, art rock and blues. Though his popularity has fluctuated
          through the years, many of Pop's songs have become well-known, including "Lust for Life", "The Passenger", "Real Wild Child", "Candy" (a duet with Kate Pierson of The B-52's), "China Girl", "Nightclubbing", "Search and Destroy" and "I Wanna
          Be Your Dog". In 2010, The Stooges were inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Back to top</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend starting over, or eliminating a lot of the code and re-inserting it piece by piece. There are a lot of things at play here that are affecting the flow of your content. For example, you have floated elements, which pull them out of the normal flow. You also have a lot of stuff positioned relatively, which isn't all that common a practice. Use margins and paddings instead of relative offsets.

Comment: Thanks @Quantastical is what I'm doing right now. I've found what is creating problems...the right part of the CV, the one with the bio and the photo but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the styling, you need to include your CSS file in your HTML file.
Anything you have to include to your HTML file, you include it in the `<head>` section. You do so by using `<link>`.

For example : `<link href="file_name.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`.

I suggest you look up http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp to get you started. They have pretty neat tutorials and they explain everything very well.

I hope you find what you need on there!

Comment: I must have missed a part copying and pasting but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. I was wondering if you only hadn't copy/pasted it or hadn't included it. Check out the CSS section of W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) for help regarding your issue

Comment: Thanks I've already had a look. I guess the problem is just bad CSS and that's totally my fault ahah